# The Promise.race() may not be suitable in getting the fastest answer?

Tags: promise, es6-promise

For example, if we were to try and get an answer from 3 servers, with some server faster but may be under heavy load:

```
let p1 = fetch("http://some-server1.com/isTwoToPowerNMinusOnePrime?n=82589933"), 
    p2 = fetch("http://some-server2.com/isTwoToPowerNMinusOnePrime?n=82589933"), 
    p3 = fetch("http://some-server3.com/isTwoToPowerNMinusOnePrime?n=82589933");

Promise.race([p1, p2, p3])
.then(console.log);
```

then this doesn't work well because if the first promise to settle is rejected (even due to network error), then the whole promise is rejected. It may be similar to a horse race where if one horse accidentally fell down, then the whole race would be canceled.

Comment: Not if *any* promise is rejected, I don't think, just if the first settlement is a rejection. It gives you the first *outcome*.

Comment: If you only want to reject once all promises are rejected, just use [`Promise.any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) instead.